# Deserialization of simple Lua table stored as string

Tags: lua, deserialization, pico-8

I'm transfering a lua table literal in a string from a web application in to PICO-8 that I'm trying to deserialize back in to a lua table in PICO-8.

The string is in the form `'{"top", {"one", {"one a", "one b"}}, {"two", {"two a", "two b"}}}'`

To try and keep things simple I'm only going to include lowercase characters in the strings and only strings are allowed in the nested tables.

I feel like I've got a grasp on parsing the characters, but I don't know how to keep track of where I am in the recreated data, both the depth of the structure and the index.

How is this usually done?

The catch is that as PICO-8 lua doesn't contain `load` or `loadstring` the parsing has to be done manually. The following code is using `table.insert` and `string.sub` instead of the PICO-8 equivalents because I'm using a lua REPL to help prototype this code.

Here is what I have so far with print statements what I think I need to do where.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
test_obj = {"top", {"one", {"one a", "one b"}}, {"two", {"two a", "two b"}}}
data_string = '{"top", {"one", {"one a", "one b"}}, {"two", {"two a", "two b"}}}'
data = nil
string = ''
level = 0
while #data_string > 0 do
 local d=string.sub(data_string,1,1)
  if stringChar(d) then
    string = string..d
  end
  if comma(d) then
    print(string)
    table.insert(data, string)
    string = ''
  end
  if openBracket(d) then
      if data == nil then
      data = {}
      print('new table')
    else
      print('insert table')
    end
    level = level + 1
    print('on level', level)
  end
  if closeBracket(d) then
    print('end of table')
    level = level - 1
    print('up to level', level)
  end
  data_string=string.sub(data_string,2)
end
```

Comment: Since `load` and `loadstring` are not available you probably also don't have LPEG, right?

Comment: Can you use `dofile` or `require`?

Comment: @HenriMenke No unfortunately. Basically just basic control flow, functions for adding to a table, substring etc. I'm not sure its the exact same as LPEG but the functions above like `openBracket()` `comma()` etc are helper functions of mine for identifying all possible characters (I'm limiting the possible chars to a-z, ", {,}  Thanks.

Comment: Are `string.sub` and `table.insert` available on PICO-8?  Probably, they have another names?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff They do have other names (sub and add). I'm prototyping in a lua repl as I find it faster to code in than the PICO 8 environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Lua patterns to avoid parsing each character

```
local function read_exp_list(s)
   local exps, res = {}, {}
   local function save(v)
      exps[#exps + 1] = v
      return ('\0'):rep(#exps)
   end
   s = s:gsub('%b{}', function(s) return save{read_exp_list(s:sub(2, -2))} end) -- arrays
   s = s:gsub('"(.-)"', save)                                                   -- strings
   s = s:gsub('%-?%d+', function(s) return save(tonumber(s)) end)               -- integer numbers
   for k in s:gmatch'%z+' do
      res[#res + 1] = exps[#k]
   end
   return (table.unpack or unpack)(res)
end

local data_string = '{-42, "top", {"one", {"one a", "one b"}}, {"two", {"two a", "two b"}}}'
local obj = read_exp_list(data_string)
-- obj == {-42, "top", {"one", {"one a", "one b"}}, {"two", {"two a", "two b"}}}
```

Strings must be enclosed in `"` and must not contain characters `{}\` inside.  String may be empty.
Numbers must be integer in decimal notation with optional minus.
Arrays must contain only strings, numbers and subarrays.  Array may be empty.

---

**UPDATE:**
The following code only uses functions `string.sub`, `table.insert`, `tonumber`, `type`

```
local function is_digit(c)
   return c >= '0' and c <= '9'
end

local function read_from_string(input)
   if type(input) == 'string' then
      local data = input
      local pos = 0
      function input(undo)
         if undo then
            pos = pos - 1
         else
            pos = pos + 1
            return string.sub(data, pos, pos)
         end
      end
   end
   local c
   repeat
      c = input()
   until c ~= ' ' and c ~= ','
   if c == '"' then
      local s = ''
      repeat
         c = input()
         if c == '"' then
            return s
         end
         s = s..c
      until c == ''
   elseif c == '-' or is_digit(c) then
      local s = c
      repeat
         c = input()
         local d = is_digit(c)
         if d then
            s = s..c
         end
      until not d
      input(true)
      return tonumber(s)
   elseif c == '{' then
      local arr = {}
      local elem
      repeat
         elem = read_from_string(input)
         table.insert(arr, elem)
      until not elem
      return arr
   end
end

local data_string = '{-42, "top", {"one", {"one a", "one b"}}, {"two", {"two a", "two b"}}}'
local obj = read_from_string(data_string)
-- obj == {-42, "top", {"one", {"one a", "one b"}}, {"two", {"two a", "two b"}}}
```

Strings must be enclosed in `"` and must not contain character `\` inside.  String may be empty.
Numbers must be integer in decimal notation with optional minus.
Arrays must contain only strings, numbers and subarrays.  Array may be empty.

Comment: That looks like a great solution I don't think PICO 8 flavored lua supports patterns like that. Sorry :(

Comment: Ops!  I didn't know PICO8 is so strange.  PICO8 is actually an emulator of never-existing game console.  In other words, you need a PC (or some other hardware running Linux) to run your game scripts in console emulator.  So why Lua is so heavily restricted in PICO8?  Actually, "sub" is the only string function available.  Meanwhile, PICO8 Lua has coroutines! :-)

Comment: Yep Pico 8 is pretty strange and cool. There are lots of artificial restrictions to give the feel of working on an old console as well as keep the project sizes small. I'm new to both lua and pico 8 so lots to learn!

Comment: BTW, there is LIKO-12 (incompatible clone of PICO8 with unrestricted Lua)

Comment: Thanks but my project is in PICO-8 :)

Comment: Thanks for your work! I wish I new about the until keyword before now!!

Comment: To make it a bit more strange, PICO-8 includes a split function, which isn't bundled by standard Lua. I think it could be used here, to make things a bit faster.